# Executing shell script from inside php code

Tags: php, json, console, youtube-dl

What I want to do is to execute `youtube-dl -x --audio-format mp3 "token"` using php and get json of following arguments:

- status (error = 0/success = 1)
- saved file url (You'll see it in console results example: `[avconv] Destination: Jennifer Lopez - Booty ft. Iggy Azalea-nxtIRArhVD4.mp3`)

Here is the PHP code that I've written.

```
<?php
if ($_GET["token"]) {
            $url =  $_GET["token"];
            $template = '/home/website/public_html/%(id)s.%(ext)s';
            $string = ('youtube-dl -x --audio-format mp3 ' . escapeshellarg($url) . ' ' . escapeshellarg($template));
            $descriptorspec = array(
                0 => array("pipe", "r"),  // stdin
                1 => array("pipe", "w"),  // stdout
                2 => array("pipe", "w"),  // stderr
            );
            $process = proc_open($string, $descriptorspec, $pipes);
            $stdout = stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
            fclose($pipes[1]);
            $stderr = stream_get_contents($pipes[2]);
            fclose($pipes[2]);
            $ret = proc_close($process);
            echo json_encode(array('status' => $ret, 'errors' => $stderr,
                'url_orginal' => $url, 'output' => $stdout,
                'command' => $string));
        }
?>
```

Basically it executes

```
youtube-dl -x --audio-format mp3 "token"
```

When I execute same command in console (via SSH) I'm getting result like that

```
[youtube] Setting language
[youtube] Confirming age
[youtube] nxtIRArhVD4: Downloading webpage
[youtube] nxtIRArhVD4: Downloading video info webpage
[youtube] nxtIRArhVD4: Extracting video information
[youtube] nxtIRArhVD4: Encrypted signatures detected.
[youtube] nxtIRArhVD4: Downloading js player vflE7vgXe
[download] Destination: Jennifer Lopez - Booty ft. Iggy Azalea-nxtIRArhVD4.m4a
[download] 100% of 3.93MiB in 00:00
[avconv] Destination: Jennifer Lopez - Booty ft. Iggy Azalea-nxtIRArhVD4.mp3
Deleting original file Jennifer Lopez - Booty ft. Iggy Azalea-nxtIRArhVD4.m4a (pass -k to keep)
```

When I execute same command in php environment getting following json result

```
    {
   "status":1,
   "errors":"WARNING: The url doesn't specify the protocol, trying with http\nWARNING: Could not send HEAD request to http:\/\/\/home\/website\/public_html\/%(id)s.%(ext)s: \nWARNING: Falling back on generic information extractor.\nERROR: Unable to download webpage: \n",
   "url_orginal":"nxtIRArhVD4",
   "output":"[youtube] Setting language\n[youtube] Confirming age\n[youtube] nxtIRArhVD4: Downloading webpage\n[youtube] nxtIRArhVD4: Downloading video info webpage\n[youtube] nxtIRArhVD4: Extracting video information\n[youtube] nxtIRArhVD4: Encrypted signatures detected.\n[youtube] nxtIRArhVD4: Downloading js player vflE7vgXe\n[download] Destination: Jennifer Lopez - Booty ft. Iggy Azalea-nxtIRArhVD4.m4a\n\r[download] 0.0% of 3.93MiB at 729.44KiB\/s ETA 00:05\r[download] 0.1% of 3.93MiB at 1.86MiB\/s ETA 00:02\r[download] 0.2% of 3.93MiB at 3.86MiB\/s ETA 00:01\r[download] 0.4% of 3.93MiB at 7.69MiB\/s ETA 00:00\r[download] 0.8% of 3.93MiB at 13.79MiB\/s ETA 00:00\r[download] 1.6% of 3.93MiB at 17.80MiB\/s ETA 00:00\r[download] 3.2% of 3.93MiB at 17.64MiB\/s ETA 00:00\r[download] 6.3% of 3.93MiB at 17.79MiB\/s ETA 00:00\r[download] 12.7% of 3.93MiB at 20.88MiB\/s ETA 00:00\r[download] 25.4% of 3.93MiB at 25.21MiB\/s ETA 00:00\r[download] 50.8% of 3.93MiB at 28.47MiB\/s ETA 00:00\r[download] 100.0% of 3.93MiB at 41.23MiB\/s ETA 00:00\r[download] 100% of 3.93MiB in 00:00\n[avconv] Destination: Jennifer Lopez - Booty ft. Iggy Azalea-nxtIRArhVD4.mp3\nDeleting original file Jennifer Lopez - Booty ft. Iggy Azalea-nxtIRArhVD4.m4a (pass -k to keep)\n[generic] %(id)s: Requesting header\n[generic] %(id)s: Downloading webpage\n",
   "command":"youtube-dl --extract-audio --audio-format mp3 'nxtIRArhVD4' '\/home\/website\/public_html\/%(id)s.%(ext)s'"
}
```

In fact php does job and saves file, but outputs are not same and I can't get destination file url.

What am I doing wrong? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your command `$string` isn't being generated properly. Your `$url` parameter may be empty.

If you look at the error it's trying to load the webpage `http:///home/website/public_html/%(id)s.%(ext)s`

Im guessing `$url` must be empty which is causing the 4th argument (your output file) become the 3rd argument (the video URL), so then it's trying to load that as a URL hence the error.

Try looking at the contents of `$url` after you initiate it, see what the value is, make sure it is actually a URL. If it is correct then check the contents of `$string` make sure the command is actually complete, and even try running that command manually and see what happens, `escapeshellarg()` may be causing more problems than it's meant to solve; I'd recommend you do some different validation on the input, for example a `preg_match()` for a YouTube URL.